# Symfony and Doctrine fixtures with single connection and multiple schemas

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I'm using Symfony and Doctrine fixtures to create a test database. Our application has a single database connection with 3 schemas and cross schema relationships.

I have 3 bundles setup each with the entity classes and fixtures for each schema. I've been able to create the cross bundle relationships but I am having issues loading fixtures using php bin/console *doctrine:fixtures:load*. Ideally I would like to be able to run something similar to the following to have my test database setup and teardown:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create / php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop
```

What should my config look like for connections and entity managers? Do I need to run each of the above for each schema and what should my mapping look like if I need multiple entity managers?

**Database Structure**

```
- Database
   - Schema1
   - Schema2
   - Schema3
```

**Bundles**

```
- Acme
   - Bundle
      - Schema1Bundle
         - Entity
         - DataFixtures
             - ORM
      - Schema2Bundle
         - Entity
         - DataFixtures
             - ORM
      - Schema3Bundle
         - Entity
         - DataFixtures
             - ORM
```

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "symfony/console": "^3.0",
    "league/flysystem": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^2.7",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3"
},
```

**config.yml**

```
orm:
auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
default_entity_manager: schema1

entity_managers:
    schema1:
        auto_mapping: false
        connection: schema1
        mappings:
            AcmeBundleSchema1Bundle: ~
            AcmeBundleSchema2Bundle: ~
            AcmeBundleSchema3Bundle: ~
```

**Example xml mapping:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Acme\Bundle\Schema1Bundle\Entity\Currency" table="schema1.currency">
  <id name="currencyCode" type="string" column="currency_code" length="3">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
  </id>
  <field name="nsInternalId" type="integer" column="ns_internal_id" nullable="true">
      <options>
          <option name="unsigned">1</option>
      </options>
   </field>
   </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I've tried using multiple entity managers but when loading fixtures, it attempts to truncate tables in incorrect schemas.

**Update:**
I receive the following error when I run doctrine:fixtures:load --em=schema1

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM boosted_user':
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'schema1.user' doesn't exist
```

The user table is in schema2 but for some reason when fixtures:load attempts to remove existing records, it tries to do so for all tables.

I've found that the ORMPurger.php does not use the schema when deleting records on line 141:

```
$this->em->getConnection()->executeUpdate("DELETE FROM " . $tbl);
```

Comment: These might be useful for you. [Using multiple SQLite entity managers for multiple bundles and databases in test environment](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5wtr/using-multiple-sqlite-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases-in-test-environment) and [Creating doctrine data fixtures in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/fj9y/creating-doctrine-data-fixtures-in-symfony) and [Using multiple MySQL entity managers for multiple bundles and databases](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7cpx/using-multiple-mysql-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases)

Comment: Thanks, these are all fairly straight forward topics, but do not go into detail on multiple schema configuration. I am yet to find an example of cross schema relationships and fixtures.